# how to use conditions inside a partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was working with partials and I was using a partial for both the index page and show page( i.e I am using the same partial for displaying an array of Products and individual product) using :collection and :object respectively. There is one segment within that block which differs for both. I cannot write it outside the partial, its embedded. Is there a way to let the partial know it and print accordingly?

Comment: I would make two separate partials. You can nest the single product partial inside the collection partial too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`render :collection=>@objs, :locals=>{:collection=>true}`

Answer (score 1):

you can check class of object in partial:

```
= render 'partial', :objekt => @colliction
= render 'partial', :objekt => @item
```

_partial.html.haml

```
- if objekt.kind_of?(Array)
  # code for collection
- else
  # code for individual product
```

- Note: I'm using haml syntax